# How to pass argument to script with ArgumentParser when invoked from another script

Tags: python

I have the following script:

`first_script.py`:

```
def register_arguments(subparser):
    subparser.add_argument(
        "-c", "--config",
    )

def __main__():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    register_arguments(parser)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    do_something(...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    __main__()
```

This script is invoked with command like and possibly adding `--config='value'`

Now I have issue where I need to invoke this script from `second_script.py` and I want also to pass `config` value

`second_script.py`:

```
from first_script import __main__ as func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func()
```

This works fine and I can execute:

```
python second_script.py
```

Now my problem is that I actually want to hard code the config.
I tried to do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    func(config='value')
```

or

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    func('config=value')
```

but this is not working.
How can I pass config from `second_script` to the `first_script` so it will mimic the way arguments are passed from command line?

To note: `first_script.py` is not mine. I'm just using it. Thus any solution involving changing it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the command line arguments directly:

```py
import sys
from first_script import __main__ as func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # modify the command line, leaving the program name as is
    sys.argv[1:] = ["--config", "value"] # sys.argv will then look like this : ["second_script.py", "--config", "value"]
    func()
```

This works, because `parser.parse_args()` reads the arguments from `sys.argv` by default.
But you should rename your `__main__` function to `main`, and then modify the imports accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

### If you have access to the first script

Firstly one should not name a function `__name__`. This name is technically reserved and could brake in future python versions. Just call the function `main` and leave `if __name__ == "__main__":` as it is.

To allow the script to be used by import one should add function arguments to `main`, so it runs without command line arguments.

As a quick fix one could just redefine the function as

```
def main(*args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    register_arguments(parser)
    args = parser.parse_args(*args)
    do_something(...)
```

then

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    func('--config', 'value')
```

should work fine (depending on the arguments allowed).

But one should better only use `argparse` for command line usage and use function arguments for this.

### If you cannot edit script 1

Don’t import but call the script from your second one.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(
              ['python', 'first_script.py', '--config', 'value'],
              stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
              stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
stdout, stderr
```

`stdout` should now contain the results.

Comment: `first_script.py` is not mine. I can't change it. I'm just using it for my process.

Comment: Oh, ok, sure then that's a totally different problem ... I'll add an answer for this case

Comment: "If you cannot edit script 1" - you forgot solution 2 for that case which you can see in my answer ;) !

Comment: @Programmer: sure that's possible. I'd call this slightly hacky though.

Comment: @matthias it works and it's simple. But it's up to the OP which solution he chooses ;) !